# How to get item from JSON-b field

Tags: postgresql

I have table with JSON-b field like this:

```
id | data
----------
1  | '{"points": [{"id": 10, "address": "Test 1"}, {"id": 20, "address": "Test 2"}, {"id": 30, "address": "Test 3"}]}'
2  | '{"points": [{"id": 40, "address": "Test 444"}, {"id": 20, "address": "Test 222"}, {"id": 50, "address": "Test 555"}]}'
```

Please note that data->'points' item with id 20 is in both lines.

The JSON-b field "data" contains "points" array. How to get the point address by id 20?
For example should get:

```
address
--------
'Test 2'
'Test 222'
```

I started trying with this query:

```
SELECT
    data
FROM test_json
WHERE
    data->'points' @> '[{"id": 20}]'
;
```

But the whole field is returned, obviously.
PostgreSQL 11

Comment: My idea is to extract the points field and flatten the json array to rows, then you can filter these rows by id column and select the address column

Comment: The point item has no clear structure. Point items can contain a different set of fields.

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using?

Comment: You only need to extract the id and address field, which you need to filter on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to unnest the array, using a lateral join with `jsonb_array_elements`, then you can filter for the individual points:

```
SELECT
    point ->> 'address' AS address
FROM test_json,
    jsonb_array_elements(data -> 'points') AS point
WHERE
    (point ->> 'id')::int = 20
```

You might be able to add `AND data @> '{"points":[{"id": 20}]}'` to speed up the search if you have an index on the `data` column.

Comment: Good trick with double FROM. Thanks you!!